# How to get LZW encode results as from example?

Tags: c, compression, lzw

Given the input from example1 on page http://michael.dipperstein.com/lzw/#example1, I am unable to get the correct result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lzw.h"

void print_hex(unsigned char str[], int len) 
{
    int idx;

    for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
        printf("%02x", str[idx]);
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fpIn;             /* pointer to open input file */
    FILE *fpOut;            /* pointer to open output file */
    FILE *fptr;

    char test_str_lzw[] = { "this_is_his_thing" };
    fptr = fopen("lzw_in_test.txt", "wb");
    fwrite(test_str_lzw, sizeof(char), strlen(test_str_lzw), fptr);
    fclose(fptr);

    fpIn = fopen("lzw_in_test.txt", "rb");
    fpOut = fopen("lzw_out.txt", "wb");

    LZWEncodeFile(fpIn, fpOut);

    fclose(fpIn);
    fclose(fpOut);

    // Getting the results from file
    if ((fptr = fopen("lzw_out.txt", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }

    unsigned char lzw_out[256];
    memset(lzw_out, 0, 256);

    size_t num;
    num = fread(lzw_out, sizeof(unsigned char), 256, fptr);


    fclose(fptr);

    unsigned int lzw_size = num;
    printf("LZW out size: %d\n", lzw_size);
    printf("LZW out data: \n");
    print_hex(lzw_out, lzw_size);
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Expected result in Hex:

```
0x74 0x68 0x69 0x73 0x5F 0x102 0x5F 0x101 0x103 0x100 0x69 0x6E 0x67
```

Result I'm getting in Hex:

```
0x74 0x34 0x1A 0x4E 0x65 0xF0 0x15 0x7C 0x03 0x03 0x80 0x5A 0x4D 0xC6 0x70 0x20
```

Can anyone help me to get output file like from the example?

Regards.

Comment: Please include the result you want and the one you get (or a complete error message) to your question. Also, `LZWEncodeFile` not defined. Thanks!

Comment: @mzuther I've edited my question, I've added lzw.h include so now LZWEncodeFile is defined. Also I've added the expected and the result I want. Thanks.

Comment: @Embedded  Aside: With `sizeof(test_str_lzw)`, the size is 18.  With `strlen(test_str_lzw)`, the length is 17.  How much of the _string_ are you trying to compress?

Comment: Post how the result was viewed from code.  The "Result I'm getting in Hex" is the right stream of bits, just not the right packing.  (notice 9 bits in expected vs 8 in seen) Post a [mcve]

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've edited question so now you can see minimal reproducible example and how I'm displaying data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LZW encoder is encoding a sequence of 9-bit code words as a sequence of 8-bit bytes. There is a mechanism for signalling an increase in the length of the code word as required, but let's ignore that for simplicity as it is not required for encoding short input sequences.

For OP's example, the first eight 9-bit code words are (in hex):

> 0x74 0x68 0x69 0x73 0x5F 0x102 0x5F 0x101

or expressed in binary:

> 001110100 001101000 001101001 001110011 001011111 100000010 001011111 100000001

The encoder splits each 9-bit code word into two groups - bits 7 to 0, followed by bit 8:

> 01110100 0 01101000 0 01101001 0 01110011 0 01011111 0 00000010 1 01011111 0 00000001 1

This is then regrouped as a sequence of 8-bit bytes:

> 01110100 00110100 00011010 01001110 01100101 11110000 00010101 01111100 00000011

or expressed in hex:

> 0x74 0x34 0x1A 0x4E 0x65 0xF0 0x15 0x7C 0x03

Comment: Thank you @Ian. You explained it perfectly, now I see what is the problem, I have to write code to covert from HEX form to 9-bit hex words to make my system work. When you say "signalling an increase in the length", can you tell me what is the length of input sequence when this happens?

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can implement inversion conversion for this in JavaScript? I need it for decompress in JavaScript.

Comment: "signalling an increase in the length" is described in the link you posted. The initial code word length is 9 which allows code word values from 0 to 510 to be output, with 511 being a reserved code that means "switch to 10-bit codes from now on". Then 10-bit code words from 0 to 1022 can be output, with 1023 being a reserved code that means "switch to 11-bit codes from now on". And so on, up to the maximum code word length of 20 bits (defined by MAX_CODE_LEN` in "lzwlocal.h").

Comment: This implementation of LZW is probably one of many implementations, that do not necessarily use exactly the same encoding scheme.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to you I was able to complete my task.